# What is the 'Stationery Pad' setting in OS X Finder?

Tags: macos, mac, finder

In the OS X Finder, when I do a Get Info on a file I notice a checkbox for 'Stationery Pad' right above 'Locked' (see attached).

What does this do?

[image: osx finder get info dialog]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[As explained here](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/04/11/tuaw-tip-stationery-pad-option-makes-a-template-of-any-file/), it turns any file into a template. Tick it and open the file, and a copy of the file will be created, ready to be saved elsewhere without affecting the original.

Comment: But it's very crude: it won't create a new document with the contents of the file; it will literally make a copy of the file the normal way and open that copy. That's it.

Comment: So if I wanted to create a template, I would need to make a 'blank' version (say, of an XHTML page with no body content) and set that as 'stationary pad' - this would let me create new versions?

Comment: As I understand it, yes; try it yourself.

Comment: Yep - works as advertised.